# MySQL: split value into multiple row, ok on MySQL 8 but not working on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, json

I'm newbie to mysql language. I'm trying to split values into multiple records, trimming the first and the last character of the record itself. My starting table is something similar:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       ~3~4~      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      ~1~5~2~     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

My desired output is:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I've modified a query that I've found online and it works on MySQL 8, but not on MySql 5.7 (which is my version)

```
select t.id, j.name
from mytable t
join json_table(
  replace(json_array((TRIM(BOTH '~' FROM t.name))), '~', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$')
) j
```

Can someone help me? Here the [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZ5k2QcteZhmuRExtN3ZpQ/5)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is maximal elements per value (final rows per one source row) amount?

Comment: I can't know the maximal elements per value.. The user insert those values and the query must be executed from another php page in order to retrieve such data in other format. Thanks

Comment: *I can't know the maximal elements per value..* What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: It's a lookup field value generated from a CRUD application (Dadabik)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mytable.name, '~', numbers.num), '~', -1) name
FROM mytable
JOIN ( SELECT 2 AS num UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ) AS numbers
HAVING name > ''
ORDER BY id, name;
```

The amount of numbers (consecutive, starting from 2) in `numbers` dynamic table must be not less than max. amount of separate values per field value (3 in shown sample data), or the rest values will be lost.

If separate values may be duplicated you may add DISTINCT.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As answer above, I can't know the maximal elements per value.. The user insert those values and the query must be executed from another php page in order to retrieve such data in other format. With your query it works only with known values, there is an alternative? Thanks

Comment: @Ale *it works only with known values* No, max. generated number must be not less - but it can be higher. For example, if the column type is VARCHAR(255), user cannot insert more than 127 tags into it, so the numbers table with numbers from 2 to 128 would be enough with guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got it